# Python iterating through each row of CSV to find partial string matches from list

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to do something that seems straightforward, but is giving me endless trouble.

What I would like to do:

```
1 for i in nameList

    2 Iterate through each row of aggregatedCSV

        3 If i is a partial match in current row, append that entire row to a new name-specific CSV

    (repeat steps 2 and 3 for remaining i in nameList)
```

`nameList = ['Jon', 'Bob', 'Tim']`

```
aggregatedCSV = [
    [1, '3', 'Bob85'], 
    [2, 'Jon52', '8'], 
    ['Bob1', '14', 3], 
    ['Tim95', 8, '6'], 
    ['8', 11, 'Tim48'], 
    [10, 'Jon11', '44'],
    [26, '21', 'Jon90'], 
    [99, '23', 'Bob19'], 
    [7, '24', 'Tim82']
    ]
```

The desired output would ultimately be three new CSV files but, to keep it simple for here, I am trying to get something like:

`JonList = [[2, 'Jon52', '8'], [10, 'Jon11', '44'],[26, '21', 'Jon90']]`

`BobList = [[1, '3', 'Bob85'], ['Bob1', '14', 3], [99, '23', 'Bob19']]`

`TimList = [['Tim95', 8, '6'], ['8', 11, 'Tim48'], [7, '24', 'Tim82']]`

Although I have manually created `nameList` for this example, I will be reading from csv files that will have an unknown number of rows, with an unknown number of values per row.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know python so there is surely a faster, more efficient way but this is what I came up with:

```
from collections import defaultdict
nameSpecificData = defaultdict(list)
for name in nameList:
  for row in aggregatedCSV:
    for item in row:
      if name in str(item):
        nameSpecificData[name].append(row)
```

This stores the results in a dictionary keyed on the name so that you don't need to know what is in the nameList in order to make output variables:

When run with your input, it results in:

```
   {
     'Jon': [[2, 'Jon52', '8'], [10, 'Jon11', '44'], [26, '21', 'Jon90']],
     'Bob': [[1, '3', 'Bob85'], ['Bob1', '14', 3], [99, '23', 'Bob19']],
     'Tim': [['Tim95', 8, '6'], ['8', 11, 'Tim48'], [7, '24', 'Tim82']]
   }
```

If you really, really want to make separate name specific variables, then this will work:

```
JonList = []
BobList = []
TimList = []
for name in nameList:
  for row in aggregatedCSV:
    for item in row:
      if name in str(item):
        globals()[name+'List'].append(row)
```

And it produces your desired output:

```
>>> print(JonList)
[[2, 'Jon52', '8'], [10, 'Jon11', '44'], [26, '21', 'Jon90']]
>>> print(BobList)
[[1, '3', 'Bob85'], ['Bob1', '14', 3], [99, '23', 'Bob19']]
>>> print(TimList)
[['Tim95', 8, '6'], ['8', 11, 'Tim48'], [7, '24', 'Tim82']]
```

Comment: Thanks @Jerry Jeremiah. It seems you know plenty of Python to me!  

I got it outputting to cvs files with your second suggestion and including this before the end of the loop:

    `file = open(folder + 'new/'  + name+'List' + '-parsed.csv', 'a', newline='')
    with file:
        write = csv.writer(file)
        write.writerows(globals()[name+'List'])`